# Django: Not allowing newly-created user to log in until he/she is approved by the admin?

Tags: python, django

I am recently trying to develop a website using Django in which a person can make his/her registration in the system but he/she should not be allowed to log in to the system until the admin approves the request. I tried the user.is_active field but the only thing it does is to prevent the new user to have access as admin. In other words, the system gives him/her permission to log in the system. My code is as follows:

```
#  create a new user but he will be inactive until admin's approval
user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
user.is_active = False
```

After changing the is_active field of the user to False I try to log in the system using the new user's username and password and the system lets me in. This is my code for the login:

```
def login(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)

    if user is not None and request.user.is_active:
        auth.login(request, user)
        print 'login'
        print request.user.username
        print request.user.is_active
        return redirect('app.views.results')

    else:
        print 'no login'
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

When I print the user's username and is_active field, I see that the "is_active" field is True instead of False. Is something wrong with the code or am I missing something?
Any better approaches to solve the problem will also be welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you saved the user after setting is_active to false?

Comment: Also note, the user won't be in request.user until *after* calling auth.login; you should be checking `user.is_active`.

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman the problem was that I wasn't saving the user. And yes, the second thing you mentioned about the user instead of request.user was also correct. I fixed the problem and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you perform value assignment for model objects' attributes, you should call object.save(), as so:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
user.is_active = False
user.save()
```

This will save the changes you've introduced to the object.

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#updating-attributes-based-on-existing-fields)

Comment: Just pass the field to `create_user`, you'll save 2 lines and 1 db query: `User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, is_active=False)`

Comment: Thank you for the remark. That obviously seems a better solution.